# How can we look same/equally to boys and girls?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In GITA  there is shloka in chapter 5 Verse 18

> **vidyā-vinaya-sampanne brāhmaṇe gavi hastini**
>
> **śhuni chaiva śhva-pāke cha paṇḍitāḥ sama-darśhinaḥ**

My thinking : I didn't deeply understand this quote

In teenage age, girl is attracted to a handsome boy, boys are attracted to beautiful girls. But we are not attracted to ugly face girls or ugly face boys.

My question is that how can we look equally to ugly face girls/boys and beautiful face boys/girls?

Is there any technique?

Comment: The last lines regarding government examination have been deleted by me, as they are not relevant to the question. @jasmine

Comment: sankrit sama darshinah means see the lord in all life forms as the  same lord who is responsible for creation, destruction, maintenance, giver of justice, giver of knowledge, obscurer of knowledge, withholding one in the material world and deliverer of liberation. it says about antaryami  in all life, material world that is  sama darshina not the external  appereance like ant and elephant, lord inside both ant and elephant are the same i.e. what sama darshina means

Comment: To be frank with all - it is not possible for ordinary people, to have sama-darśhinaḥ or having equal perception, but not equal look.  This stage is possible to a person, who attained SELF REALISATIOIN.  The subtle concept is that a SELF REALISED person (he/she) will not perceive he/she is the human body, but the DIVINE soul.  The moment ONE start thinking that ONE is body, all types of emotions, ie., anger, passion, desire for mating with opposite sex, happiness, will creep in.

Comment: Gita is basically a crash course guide on Vedanta and Puranas. So, to truly understand it, one must study Vedanta-Puranas under a competent Guru. In 5.18, Krishna is talking about the soul, even though elephant, cow, dog, chandala appear different externally, but internally their cause is same. Shankaracharya learnt this oneness from a Chandala of Kashi. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-MVCn_tO1Q . Everyone is attracted to a beautiful face & want to be young forever, because everyone is knowingly/unknowingly striving for perfection.'Satyam Shivam Sundaram',only truth is beautiful and immortal

Comment: thanks u @ManuKumar.

Comment: I have also wondered this too. But sometimes so call “ugly” people are much more attractive than nice looking people due to how they kind of present themselves, talking, moving, behaving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be frank with all - it is not possible for ordinary people, to have sama-darśhinaḥ or having equal perception. This stage is possible to a person, who attained SELF REALISATION.

The subtle concept is that a SELF REALISED person (he/she) will not perceive he/she is the human body, but the DIVINE soul. The moment ONE start thinking that ONE is body, all types of emotions, ie., anger, passion, desire for mating with opposite sex, happiness, will creep in.

---

The following is an excerpt from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> D.: How to root out sexual impulse?
>
> M.: By rooting out the false idea of the body being Self. There is no
> sex in the Self.
>
> D.: How to realise it?
>
> M.: Because you think you are the body, you see another as the body.
> Difference in sex arises. But you are not the body. Be the real Self.
> Then there is no sex.